# How can i scroll to last item of Qooxdoo virtualist

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I want to autoscroll to end of last item of the virtual list, as soon as new data is pushed into it.
Is there bult-in feature for it? 
How can i get lastitem's position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scroll to the end, there is no need to know the exact position of the last item. Just scroll to an incredible high number and your good like `1e99` e.g.

Check out this playground sample to see how it could be done: http://tinyurl.com/pbcprht

Comment: i did that , it works , but feels a little bit dirty :D . Can you guide me a proper way to do it?